# How to determine the ANOVA table for split-plot with repeated measures experiment?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, split-plot

I have an experiment where observations are one of eight different treatment combinations and are then either one of two different heights. There are 4 blocks, with 8 plots for each block, and the two heights are thought of as split-plots.

I.e. the data table resembles:

[image]

I don't know how to set up the anova table, i.e. the sources of variation. Would somebody mind running through the set up of the sources of variation with me as I understand that in some cases split plot analysis can be used for repeated measures experiment. In this case when there are only two repeated measures, so split plot methods can be used I just am at a loss when it comes to the analysis of variance table.

As i am a new user I cannot post the data table. The treatments in the experiment consist of 8 combinations of factor C (1,2,3,4) and factor D (1,2). There are 4 blocks each with the 8 plots per block, the different heights are split-plots. So there are 64 observations, i.e 32 per height (ground level and 10m)

Comment: Hmm, picture is missing... If you can't attach it, put it on some picture hosting site and paste the URL, I'll fix it then.

Comment: Well I also asked the question here and i was able to attach the file: http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?p=35377513&highlight=

Comment: How do I give reputation points to those who replied and attached the file? Is the graph clear or should I put up all 8 treatment combinations for each block.

Comment: You can't; yet small maintenance is our mod duty.